# How do you insure mutual exclusion for data structures?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I heard the same rule that applies for variables doesn't apply when we're talking about data structures. Is this true?

For instance, this, which is perfectly fine

```
public class SynchronizedCounter {
    private int c = 0;

    public synchronized void increment() {
        c++;
    }

    public synchronized void decrement() {
        c--;
    }

    public synchronized int value() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

does not mean that the following will work flawlessly.

```
public class SynchronizedDataStructures {
    private ArrayList<String> c = new ArrayList<String>();

    public synchronized void add1(element) {
        c.add(element);
    }

    public synchronized void clear1() {
        c.clear();
    }

    public synchronized int value() {
        return c;
    }
}
```

Is this true and what can I do to make it work for data structures?

Comment: Well...`value()` won't compile. If you meant to make it return a `ArrayList`, you'd be leaking a reference to the `ArrayList`. Whoever has that reference can now access the object without the appropriate synchronization.

Comment: I believe it is almost impossible to discuss without proper context of where you heard about "rules on variable does not apply to data structure".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change `add1(element)` to `add1(String element)`, and remove the `value()` method, this will compile, and be thread safe.

You will need a method which correctly accessing the contents of the list. e.g.

```
public synchronized int value(int index) {
    return c.get(index);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a more clean way to synchronize on an object and not on a complete method. Consider this:

```
...
    public void clear1() {
        synchronized(c) {
            c.clear();
        }
    }
...
```

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html

This is a nice explanation of synchronized in Java.